# Get a string coming after a work

Tags: javascript

I have a string as follows or it can be anything similar to this:

```
http://localhost:3003/?sp-tk=A8FEE0A4AFD2A086277CC79449AD69E5D34734455900AEED7C0A7C77EC580187D9D2FE1B286F7B5989B421B27E6FE2D1CAD2CCEB4372A80FFF6DC5D1AC6E246DB3BBAD7EB8DD7DAD1C5ED79A2114F0E3A036E898287021ABEFE642F74FAE5372E6525E0C54732B7EA9691F84C27EEB6AE60029B7613B68DA8DA3AE69887F6E815EA0A3415F08C827AF21DBFB82AE7247B297F8CFAD0DD3F7D0ED81FC095375F6242CED940B2B55D8707BCB1D85E54CBB98E83CB8
```

What I need is the section after sp-tk:

```
A8FEE0A4AFD2A086277CC79449AD69E5D34734455900AEED7C0A7C77EC580187D9D2FE1B286F7B5989B421B27E6FE2D1CAD2CCEB4372A80FFF6DC5D1AC6E246DB3BBAD7EB8DD7DAD1C5ED79A2114F0E3A036E898287021ABEFE642F74FAE5372E6525E0C54732B7EA9691F84C27EEB6AE60029B7613B68DA8DA3AE69887F6E815EA0A3415F08C827AF21DBFB82AE7247B297F8CFAD0DD3F7D0ED81FC095375F6242CED940B2B55D8707BCB1D85E54CBB98E83CB8
```

To do so I found a code as follows:

```
function getTokenFromUrl() {
    name="sp-tk";
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,
        "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(
            /\+/g, " "));
}
```

and it works. But I do not understand the regular expression parts. Can anyone shed a light on that and also if there is a simpler way and maybe cleaner achieving that?

Comment: The regex is extracting a param from query string, you can do a simple split by "sp-tk=" and get the right part but if you have additional params in the query string this will fail to get correct data.

Comment: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code (i think this regex easier to read):

```js
    var myString = 'http://localhost:3003/?sp-tk=A8FEE0A4AFD2A086277CC79449AD69E5D34734455900AEED7C0A7C77EC580187D9D2FE1B286F7B5989B421B27E6FE2D1CAD2CCEB4372A80FFF6DC5D1AC6E246DB3BBAD7EB8DD7DAD1C5ED79A2114F0E3A036E898287021ABEFE642F74FAE5372E6525E0C54732B7EA9691F84C27EEB6AE60029B7613B68DA8DA3AE69887F6E815EA0A3415F08C827AF21DBFB82AE7247B297F8CFAD0DD3F7D0ED81FC095375F6242CED940B2B55D8707BCB1D85E54CBB98E83CB8'

    var myRegexp = /sp-tk=(.*?)(&|$)/;
    var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
    var spTk = match[1]
    console.log(spTk);
```

**Regex explanation**

- `sp-tk=` => Find a string that starts with sp-tk=
- `(.*?)` => The string should be followed by any characters (the ? stand for non-greedy mode) and sourounded with parenthesis because we want to extract the match of this part.
- `&|$` Since we are in non-greedy mode, we have to say on which characters the .*? should stop.

Then you get the match at index `1` because 0 is the whole match (including sp-tk)

Note that  this regex will work event if there are other url params before or after sp-tk.

Comment: Can you explain this part more: Get the string after sp-tk= and until & or end of line occurs.

Comment: Thanks still I do not get this part: &|$ : Since we are in non-greedy mode, we have to say on which characters the .*? should stop.

Comment: You want to match all the caracters until you encounter `&` (which means that another parameters is appended to the url), or until you encounter `$` (which in regex language stands for `end of line`). This is needed because i used `.*?` and this expression need to know until when it should match, if i had used `.*` instead it will have matched until the end of the line automatically.